# Compute a quantile of F distribution?

Tags: quantiles, f-distribution

I'm looking for the meaning of this definition of $q$, found in a chapter on non-linear regression.

"$q=q_{1-\alpha}^{F_{p,n-p}}$ is the $(1-\alpha)$ quantile of the $F$ distribution with $p$ and $n-p$ degrees of freedom."

Here $\alpha$ is a probability (e g, 0.05) and I know how to calculate $F_{p,n-p}$. I need to compute $q$ per the definition above.

Note: I am not looking for how to do this computation in any package, as I will be implementing this in a programming language as part of a larger application.

Comment: Why do you need to compute it?

Comment: It will be used to determine the confidence interval for parameters fit by non-linear regression.

Comment: There is no simple closed formula for quantile function of $F$ distribution. Maybe there is some infinite series formula but i haven't seen such. AFAIK packages calculate it numerically. So either way you will get some approximation of quantiles

Comment: @Łukasz Your analysis could be used to conclude that the computer's evaluation of elementary functions like $\exp$ and $\sin$ and $\log$ must--because they are defined as power series--also be "approximate"!  The fact that an expression has no "closed form" does not mean that the calculations are any less accurate than if they do have a closed form. As a matter of fact, though, the quantile function for the $F$ distribution (with integral or half-integral degrees of freedom) can be computed exactly as a finite sum using the Binomial distribution.

Comment: @whuber Yes you are right, maybe approximation was a wrong word. Nonetheless they all are not exact, but we can control the error. What is more, they can't ever be exact, apart from finite subset, since we have limited precision of computer words :)

Comment: @Łukasz It can be worth bearing in mind that some computer algebra systems, like *Mathematica*, can perform exact calculations in many cases.

Comment: The question is, what does the definition of q as given in the original post mean. I have a working pgm to compute FInverse(m,n,p) m,n=degrees of freedom and p=probability.